# AzCopy Authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, azcopy

A client has given us the following information to copy data into their storage account. ClientID,TenantID,URL,OAuthStorageAccountName,AzureStorageAccountName,ClientSecret,ContainerName. I can't seem to find a simple answer to the question of authentication. We want to use AzCopy in a scripted environment to copy a large number of files into the account. What is the simplest way to authenticate?

Answer (score 2):

(Examples in PowerShell)

First, make sure you're using a recent version of AzCopy that supports OAuth for BOTH source and destination.

Then, set these environment variables:

```
$Env:AZCOPY_AUTO_LOGIN_TYPE="SPN";
$Env:AZCOPY_TENANT_ID=[TenantId];
$Env:AZCOPY_SPA_APPLICATION_ID=[ClientID];
$Env:AZCOPY_SPA_CLIENT_SECRET=[ClientSecret];
```

Finally, use `azcopy copy` as normal:

```
azcopy copy [source URI] [destination URI]
```

AzCopy will look for these environment variables and handle the authentication in an unattended fashion.

Here is [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-authorize-azure-active-directory#authorize-a-service-principal-1) for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

you could auth with a certificate:

```
azcopy login --service-principal --certificate-path /path/to/my/cert --application-id <your service principal's application ID>
```

or using a managed identity:

```
azcopy login --identity
```

you can also auth via a SAS token (cant find an example right now).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-authorize-azure-active-directory

Answer (score 0):

You could authenticate with [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id=<ClientID>
&scope=https://storage.azure.com/.default
&client_secret=<ClientSecret>
&grant_type=client_credentials
```